# Status bar icon white color

Tags: android, xml, android-styles

I added lines below to `styles.xml(v23)` it changes status bar icon color to white, but when I run app on `27API` emulator icons becomes dark grey color any idea why?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: try using it on a real device

Comment: So it's most likely emulators problem? I mean if it works with all 23> api emulators

Comment: yes, it might be. Just give it try on real device